# Image separator for rows in jsf data table

Tags: jsf-2

I want to display an line/image as separator ( as shown here - image attached) between rows conditionally, and I have no idea on how to achieve this, please suggest, this is my sample that I have written to replicate the actual scenario,

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" >
<h:dataTable value="#{testBean.myBeanList}" var="myBean">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">  
<h:outputText value="EMPLOYEE NAME"  />  
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.empName}"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">  
<h:outputText value="EMPLOYEE DEPARTMENT"  />  
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.empDept}"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">  
<h:outputText value="EMPLOYEE HR NAME"  />  
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.empHRName}"/>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>



public TestBean() {
myBeanList = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
for(int i =0;i<8;i++){
MyBean mb = new MyBean();
if(i == 2 || i == 4){
mb.setEmpName("NAME"+i);
}else{
mb.setEmpName("EMPLOYEE NAME"+i);
mb.setEmpDept("EMPLOYEE DEPT"+i);
mb.setEmpHRName("EMPLOYEE HR NAME"+i);
}
myBeanList.add(mb);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `rowClasses` attribute of the `<h:dataTable>`. It takes a commaseparated string of CSS class names which are applied on the subsequent generated `<tr>` elements. You can then use CSS to put a top border in every cell (`<td>`) of the `<tr>` in question (those with "NAME2" and "NAME4" in your example).

```
<h:dataTable ... rowClasses="#{bean.rowClasses}">
```

At the same time of populating the data model, you should also populate the row classes. It should for the particular exapmle in the screenshot return something like this:

```
none,none,separator,none,separator,none,none,none
```

Then you just have to provide the necessary CSS:

```css
tr.separator td {
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
```

No need for an ugly and old fashioned separator image.